# MySQL request with a condition on two columns

Tags: mysql, request

I have this table in `MySQL` database :

table1

```
User_id   type
2          1
1          2    
2          3
```

I want to get the users_id of users with type 2 or 3 only when their user_id value is different from the user_id with the type=1.

hope you got the idea and you can help me I didn't know what to use to solve his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the users_id of users with type 2 or 3 only when their user_id value is different from the user_id with the type=1.

It can be written pretty much the same in SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE type IN (2,3) and user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE type = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
user_id,
type,
FROM
yourTable
WHERE type IN (2,3)
AND user_id NOT IN (
   SELECT
   user_id
   FROM yourTable
   WHERE type = 1)
```